# MySQL, trying to sort a joined table to get the latest row for a customers order, to see when they last ordered

Tags: mysql, sorting, join

I'm running through a list of users/customers and joining to the order file using the user_id as the join, then updating the customer table with the last ordered date.
What is happening is it is bringing back the oldest/first row and not the last/latest row, I've tried every which way, but it just doesn't seem to like anything I do regards to sorting/ordering the table in the statement...

Getting desperate now
How do I get the latest row from the order file?

Thanks in advance...

```
UPDATE j423_customer_

JOIN j423_hikashop_order ON j423_customer_.user_id = j423_hikashop_order.order_user_id 

SET j423_customer_.lastordereddate = j423_hikashop_order.order_created,    j423_customer_.lastordereddatehuman = FROM_UNIXTIME(j423_hikashop_order.order_created) 

WHERE j423_hikashop_order.order_status = "addedtocadpostagelabelfile"
OR j423_hikashop_order.order_status = "shipped"
OR j423_hikashop_order.order_status = "mailmergeadded"
AND (j423_hikashop_order.order_created >= '1445836026');
```